# Need wiring help to use a Raspberry 4B with a Mac, Octoprint and Longer LK5 3d printer

Tags: wiring

I know where to apply the 5 volts for power. So far it appears that a cable is supposed to connect the 3D printers USB port to one of the Raspberry Pi 4B USB ports.

An SD card plugs into the Pi 4B but is one also needed in the printer SD port as in the one that came with the printer? I'm assuming it's not.

How is the Pi 4B connected to the Mac to use Octoprint and is a direct cable better or easier than Wi-Fi? If Wi-Fi is better how is that wired?

I've seen a lot of videos about using a Raspberry Pi with Octoprint for 3D printer control but the wiring details are skipped over.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You just need octoprint installed on the SD card you   use to boot the Pi.  You do not need one for the printer.

Octoprint provides a web interface for control.  Just navigate to the octoprint web address on your Mac with your favourite browser. This assumes you have a wifi router which gives out an address to your Pi and your Mac.